# webjob aborts with exception somehow due to idling to long

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am extracting a .zip archive on azure webjob.

That worked ok for some time.

Now the webjob suddenly started to fail:

```
[12/11/2017 16:59:57 > bf607f: ERR ] Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""run.cmd""
[12/11/2017 16:59:57 > bf607f: ERR ] replace D:\home\site\store\extracted/documents/6465465465466015.pdf? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: 
[12/11/2017 16:59:57 > bf607f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[12/11/2017 16:59:57 > bf607f: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""run.cmd""
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteInternal(ITracer tracer, Func`2 onWriteOutput, Func`2 onWriteError, Encoding encoding, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.ExecuteReturnExitCode(ITracer tracer, Action`1 onWriteOutput, Action`1 onWriteError, String arguments, Object[] args)
   at Kudu.Core.Jobs.BaseJobRunner.RunJobInstance(JobBase job, IJobLogger logger, String runId, String trigger, ITracer tracer, Int32 port)
---> (Inner Exception #0) ExitCode: -1, Output: Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Error: Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed., Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c ""run.cmd""' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121 seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.
cmd /c ""run.cmd""
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.IdleManager.WaitForExit(IProcess process)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.ProcessExtensions.<Start>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.Executable.<ExecuteAsync>d__31.MoveNext()<---
```

I mean it seems when the exception happened the webjob was pretty busy, so why do I get that idle timeout exception?

Answer (score 1):

> I mean it seems when the exception happened the webjob was pretty busy, so why do I get that idle timeout exception?

**Root Cause:**

There is no output in the console for long time.

**Solution:**

We also could do as Ashok metioned to increase **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** value.This should be set in the configuration **setting for the Web App**, rather than in the App.config of the WebJob. And the value is in second.

You also could add output to the console every minute. More details could refer to this [blog](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/jaredjohnson/2017/05/15/preventing-idle-timeout-in-triggered-azure-webjobs-jobs).

> **Another solution** is to  add output to the Console, which is especially useful for jobs that are doing long running asynchronous tasks or polling external services, For these cases adding a heartbeat style Console write every minute is better than increasing the Idle Timeout to huge numbers